# How to fill in input with a var value?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I fill in input with a var value?

For example: number= 10, user clicks button, input auto 'types' number 10.

```js
var number = 10;
```

```html
<input type="number">

<button onclick="value()">Fill in value</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the element and set it's value. Use `document.getElementById()` to get the `input` element and use `value` property to set it's value;

```js
var number = 10;

var txt = document.getElementById('txt');

function setValue(){
  txt.value = number;
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" type="number">

<button onclick="setValue()">Fill in value</button>
```

Comment: is there a way to have the input *2 on a click? eg. input has 10 now, user clicked button, input sows 20

Comment: It is a basic operation. `value * 2` is assigned to the `txt.value`